# Chaincode Deployment Failed

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger fabric. When I am trying to install the Chaincode, I am getting the below error :

Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'ApproveChaincodeDefinitionForMyOrg': attempted to redefine uncommitted sequence (1) for namespace marbles03 with unchanged content

Please shed a light on this.
Thank you

Comment: What was the command that you used?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some Googling, I found [Nikhil Gupta's answer](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/errors_with_the_tutorial/71678251) on the hyperledger.org site to be helpful.

> This message states that you have already approved the chaincode definition as this org. The chaincode definition with sequence 1 has already been defined for that organization, and you cannot define the same sequence again.

Assuming that you are executing the `peer lifecycle chaincode approvemyorg` command, you have already approved the chaincode definition with sequence 1, and you cannot redefine it for this organization.